# How to create a file "hyperlink" in word to open a file?

Tags: c#

I have a C# console application that processes a bunch of files.

It has been requested to have the log file be a word document and include hyperlinks to the files that were processed (takes the place of the line "document.Content.Text += file.Path + Environment.NewLine".

How can I produce these links within the code?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
public void FinishLogFile()
    {
        var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        word.Visible = false;

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        var document = word.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);

        document.Content.Text = "User: " + userName + Environment.NewLine;

        if (processedFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            document.Content.Text += "Successful files";
            foreach (var file in processedFiles)
            {
                document.Content.Text += "File name: " + file.FileName;
                document.Content.Text += file.Path + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        if (unprocessedFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            document.Content.Text += "********************************************************************************";
            document.Content.Text += "" + Environment.NewLine;
            document.Content.Text += "Unsuccessful files" + Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (var file in unprocessedFiles)
            {
                document.Content.Text += "File name: " + file.FileName;
                document.Content.Text += file.Path + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        document.Content.Text += "********************************************************************************";
        document.Content.Text += "Application Log" + Environment.NewLine;
        foreach (var line in activityLogs)
        {
            document.Content.Text += line;
        }

        object filename = logFileName + ".docx";
        document.SaveAs2(ref filename);
        document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        document = null;
        word.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        word = null;
    }
```

Comment: Give the `Hyperlinks.Add` method a try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.hyperlinks.add.aspx

Comment: I've tired that and what I'm getting is the existing hyperlink is being overridden. I've tried the following altered the range, releasing the document using the System Marshal, setting the range and document to null, closing and reopening the document, and closing and reopening the word application, but still the document resets the hyperlink to the last range.